# Distribution of last digits in fibonacci series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I've found out that the distribution of the last digits in the fibonacci series is $0.07$, $0.13$, $0.07$, $0.13$, $0.07$, $0.13$, $0.07$, $0.13$, $0.07$, $0.13$. Is there a reason for this, or is it just by coincidence like this?

Comment: How did you find it?  Please include these details in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fibonacci modulo $2$ is $0,1,1,\cdots$ (repeats with cycle length $3$).

Fibonacci modulo $5$ is $0,1,1,2,3,0,3,3,1,4,0,4,4,3,2,0,2,2,4,1,\cdots$ (repeats with cycle length $20$).

Note that the remainders mod $5$ occur with the same frequency in each such repeating interval, so each occurs $\frac15$ of the time.

Also, $\gcd(3,20) = 1$, so all possible pairings occur in every interval of length $3·20 = 60$.

The last digit is determined by mod $2$ and mod $5$. For example, $8$ is $0$ mod $2$ and is $3$ mod $5$, so it occurs as last digit whenever you get the pairing $(0,3)$, which occurs $\frac13·\frac15$ of the time. For another example, $7$ corresponds to the pairing $(1,2)$, which occurs $\frac23·\frac15$ of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Some observations:

(1): You're looking at the Fibonacci sequence (mod 10). This sequence will repeat with a period of at most 100 (since each term depends only on the previous 2 terms and there are only 100 possibilities for two consecutive terms of last digits). In fact the period is shorter than 100, as you can explore.

(2) If you start the Fibonacci sequence with 0, 1, the pattern is even, odd, odd; even, odd, odd; etc.  So asymptotically there will be twice as many odd last digits as even last digits.

(3) Because of the short period (see (1) above), you can easily calculate the exact (asymptotic) distribution of last digits.